# Google Developers Console no longer showing Requests, Errors or Charges

Tags: google-cloud-platform

The Google Developers Console is no longer showing any values for Requests, Errors or Charges. It has been this way for over a week now, and we've not changed anything at our end.

Also, the page looks different now; the project table used to fill the page width, now it appears to be fixed-width with a grey area to the right. I think this change happened at the same time as the values disappearing, which leads me to suspect that Google have changed something.

Anyone else having this problem? How do I get the values back?

Comment: Is your app still serving traffics or not ?

Comment: The application is working fine. We use the requests and errors values as they are a good indication if something is going wrong.

Comment: I do not encounter the same issue you're experiencing. But I recommend you to open a issue at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list to have some one from Google to look into your project internally to fix your issue.

Comment: Also feel free to send a feedback report from within the console upper right corder there is an icon for feedback.  That way we can get a screenshot and project info to tract down the issue

Comment: @Army-L: I've opened an issue at the URL you suggested. Someone at Google has replied, and apparently that is the intended behaviour of the console. Strange because we used to see values, and now do not. If you're a Google engineer, you might be able to see the issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12003)

Comment: @DavidFrankland I think you should click on the project to enter the project console, then click on 'Overview' (at the left top of the page) which should show what you're looking for, such as Requests/sec.